# Should I disclose the reasons why I am looking for a new job during an interview?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, salary

When you're interviewing in a new company, while still working in your current role, should you tell your interviewer that you're leaving the company because you haven't been paid for 3 months, and for 3 more months you didn't receive a full salary?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> should you tell your interviewer that you're leaving the company because you haven't been paid for 3 months, and for 3 more months you didn't receive a full salary?

Only do it when and *if* asked.

Try to keep your answer brief and honest, and stick to the facts (so it does not come out as you venting out with your current employer).

Anyways, I feel that saying that you are seeking a new job because payment is inconsistent is a valid thing to say. No need to give specific details on how many months or the amount of money.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fine line between being truthful and spreading rumours.  I think this is probably over the line.  If you wanted to say something like this, I would say:

> My current company isn't doing well financially and I'm worried about my company's future, so I'm choosing to be proactive and hunt for a job earlier rather than later.

This shows the interviewing company that you are not unemployed, and does not give them the information that you are not *gainfully* employed (which is important leverage; you will get a better offer if you are gainfully employed and get lowballed if the recruiter thinks otherwise), and also shows them that you are not terminated for cause (so they don't have to worry about your performance) while also getting across the idea that you need something new in the near term because, by no fault of your own, you may find yourself unemployed soon (but nobody knows how soon).

It should go without saying, but also you should not answer this question unless prompted directly.

Comment: IMHO saying that *"my current company isn't doing well financially"* is spreading rumours. We don't know if the company isn't doing well financially. The fact that OP isn't being paid does not mean that the company has low funds (it could be that they are taking advantage of OP, or that the one in charge of the payroll is not doing a proper work).

Comment: @DarkCygnus I'd prefer to speculate that the company is not maliciously screwing over OP.  If you say anything about not getting paid, then the only conclusion is either the company has no money or OP is being maliciously affected.  I think this is the more diplomatic way to raise the issue.

Comment: "I haven't been paid correctly for 6 months" would be true, rather than a rumour. In this situation it seems silly to be concerned about protecting your current employers reputation.

Comment: @P.Hopkinson It's not about protecting your current employer's reputation.  It's about not giving off the appearance of being someone who goes around complaining to unconcerned third parties about your difficulties at work.  The interviewing company wouldn't want to hire a person who will go out after work and start complaining to everyone about how shitty their job is (not that we don't all do it anyway but that's not the face you want to put forward).

Comment: @DarkCygnus It could also be the fault of a badly broken payroll system. There was a scandal a few years back when Queensland Health’s new payroll system broke and started failing to pay doctors, for instance.